# How can I select that an item of array exists in other multidimensional array or not

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, smarty

I have a problem, I would like to view that a value (id_person) of a multidimensional array exists in other multidimensional array or not. (id_person is the value what I would like to compare in these two arrays - Eddie Taylor: id_person 302 and Jack Jones: id_person 311 exists in second array ). I hope someone could help for me. Many thanks.

```
Array one: ($homesquad)

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "277"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "306"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Mark Jones"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["captain"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "282"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "311"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Jack Jones"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["captain"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "273"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "302"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Eddie Taylor"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["captain"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "270"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "299"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Jonas Haverla"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["captain"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["pos"]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

```
Array two ($homeabsences)

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "265"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "294"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Harry Jackson"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "269"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "311"
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "Jack Jones"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "288"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "302"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Eddie Taylor"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "286"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(2) "14"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "315"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Terry Barnes"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "277"
    ["id_club"]=>
    string(2) "44"
    ["id_season"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["id_person"]=>
    string(3) "366"
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Jerry O'Donald"
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
}
```

My current (UPDATED) code (which not working):

```
{foreach item=player from=$homesquad}
{if $player.pos == $count}  (filtering the first array based on pos value)

{if in_array("id_person",$homeabsences)}
Do X.
{else}
Do Y.
{/if}
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find all values of id_person in an array use the array_column function. Then you can find if it overlaps:

```
array_intersect(
    array_column($homesquad, 'id_person'), 
    array_column($homeabsences, 'id_person')
)
```

Or for a single value

```
in_array($player['id_person'], array_column($homeabsences, 'id_person'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to get values found in both the first array and the second array. Try this code:

```
<?php

//First array
$homesquad = array(
    array(
        "id" => "270",
        "id_club" => "44",
        "id_season" => "2",
        "position" => "8",
        "id_person" => "306",
        "name" => "Mark Jones",
        "type" => "2",
        "captain" => "0",
        "pos" => "1"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "273",
        "id_club" => "44",
        "id_season" => "2",
        "position" => "4",
        "id_person" => "302",
        "name" => "Eddie Taylor",
        "type" => "2",
        "captain" => "0",
        "pos" => "6"
    )
);

//Second array
$homeabsences = array(
    array(
        "id" => "277",
        "id_club" => "44",
        "id_season" => "2",
        "position" => "8",
        "id_person" => "366",
        "name" => "Jerry O'Donald",
        "type" => "2",
        "captain" => "0",
        "pos" => "1"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => "273",
        "id_club" => "44",
        "id_season" => "2",
        "position" => "4",
        "id_person" => "302",
        "name" => "Eddie Taylor",
        "type" => "2",
        "captain" => "0",
        "pos" => "6"
    )
);

//get intersection between $homesquad and $homeabsences
$id_persons =  array_intersect(
    array_column($homesquad, 'id_person'), 
    array_column($homeabsences, 'id_person')
);

if($id_persons)
    print_r($id_persons); //this will display the intersection of two arrays
else
    echo "no matches"
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I would like to compare just one array (player) not the whole multidimensional array (homesquad). (the result of foreach cycle is just one array - one player). I would like to compare that array with the id_persons of homeabsences array. If I replace $homesquad with $player then it will works?

Comment: So the most important: the result of foreach cycle is just one array, and I would like check that the id_person of this array (player) exists or not in the homeabsences (multidimensional) array.